# Start vb.net application before windows login

Tags: vb.net, windows, startup

On my server pc I have a simple vb.net application running on windows startup. Currently I simply added it to the StartUp folder in AppData. This works fine except I have to remotely connect and login to my server pc after each restart, before the application will start up. How do i make my application start up with out me having to login first? I know it's possible since a lot of programs dont require you to login on the machine first like teamviewer and my sql server.

Comment: Make it a [service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Window's `Task Scheduler` for this purpose:

**Basic settings**

1. Open the Task Scheduler (you may search for it in the Start Menu).
2. In the `Actions` panel click `Create Task...`.
3. Enter a name and description (the latter is optional) for your task.
4. Select `Run whether user is logged on or not` and possibly `Do not store password.`.

**Adding a trigger**

1. Go to the `Triggers` tab and click `New...`.
2. In the `Begin the task` box select `At startup`.
3. Make sure `Enable` is ticked, then press `OK`.

**Specifying an action**

1. Go to the `Actions` tab and click `New...`.
2. In the `Action` box select `Start a program`.
3. In the `Program/script` box enter the path to your application.
4. Press `OK` and you're done!

---

**Read more about the Task Scheduler:**

- [**Task Scheduler - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [**Schedule a Task - TechNet**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)